# I can't see my logs in Android Studio logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Here's a simple app, I'm trying to create logs in the printToLogs method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v("Log0","test");
}

public void printToLogs(View view){
    TextView menuTextView1 = findViewById(R.id.menu_item_1);
    TextView menuTextView2 = findViewById(R.id.menu_item_2);
    TextView menuTextView3 = findViewById(R.id.menu_item_3);

    String item1 = (String) menuTextView1.getText();
    String item2 = (String) menuTextView2.getText();
    String item3 = (String) menuTextView3.getText();

    Log.v("Log1",item1);
    Log.v("Log2",item2);
    Log.v("Log3",item3);

}
```

but logs with the tags Log1, Log2, Log3 are not shown at all in the logcat, what *does* show up is the Log0 in the onCreate method, but the other ones in printToLogs never show up when I search for them *at all*. I attempted re-installing the app and restarting logging. That didn't work.

The menu items are: Mango sorbet, Blueberry pie, Chocolate lava cake. And yes, I tried searching for them, and they are not in the logcat either.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, you aren't even calling `printToLogs` in the `onCreate` method. You should be more diligent before posting something simple like this.

Comment: I'll admit that the fix turned out to be something super dumb. But this has nothing to do with my error at all. I managed to fix it without calling printToLogs in onCreate.

Comment: That's fine, but you posted limited code and didn't mention that you were calling your method somewhere else. Try ensuring that when you post you give all context surrounding your method in question.

Comment: Ok. I'll keep this in mind in my next questions! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Barring a serious runtime environment issue, this problem should be fairly easy to solve.

It seems as if the printToLogs(View view) method is to be executed in response to the user clicking a button. If so, try including the following line in your activity_main.xml if you haven't already:

```
android:onClick="printToLogs"
```

This will bind the button on the UI with the printToLogs(View view) method.

If, on the other hand, printToLogs(View view) is intended to be a standalone method (i.e. one that should execute regardless of user input) it should not accept a View as an argument. For your purposes, its parameter list should be completely empty. In other words, the method signature should read:

```
public void printToLogs()
```

Also, it should be called within the onCreate(Bundle savedInstances) method. Add the following to the onCreate(Bundle savedInstances) method:

```
printToLogs();
```

This will initiate the execution of the method as soon as the app begins to run.

Make sure the logcat filter is set to "Verbose" when testing like so: (img is link since apparently I need 10 rep. to embed images into answers directly)
[logcat filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNa3V.png)

Comment: Ok.. I solved it... had to actually press the button for the Logs to show up in the logcat...

Answer (score 0):

heyy add your method/function name in your button by using property section or just android:onClick in your xml file and then it will be solved